# php - ftp all files in a directory?

Tags: php, ftp

Trying to use php to get all files in a directory and save them locally... It seems like I constantly need to specify a name?  Is that right?

```
function grabFiles() {
         $conn = ftp_connect(REMOTE);
             @ftp_login($conn, REMOTEUSER, REMOTEPASS);
             ftp_get($conn, '*', FTP_BINARY);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a list of all the files using `ftp_nlist`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Go through that array and download each file using `ftp_fget`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php

Comment: Good solution, clean and simple.  No need to over engineer.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a `ftp_glob` function as I also needed it in a project. It works exactly like [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), but without any option.

<kbd>Usage example</kbd>

```
$ftp = ftp_connect($server, $port, 90);
ftp_login($ftp, $login, $password);
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);

$list = ftp_glob($ftp, "/sample/*.csv");
```

<kbd>Code</kbd>

```
function ftp_glob($resource, $pattern)
{
   $dir_patterns = explode('/', ltrim($pattern, '/'));
   if (count($dir_patterns) == 0)
   {
      return array ();
   }
   $paths_to_check = array (ftp_pwd($resource));
   return ftp_glob_rec($resource, $dir_patterns, $paths_to_check);
}

function ftp_glob_rec($resource, $dir_patterns, $paths_to_check)
{
   $matching_paths = array();
   $pattern = array_shift($dir_patterns);
   foreach ($paths_to_check as $path)
   {
      $list = ftp_nlist($resource, $path);
      if ($list === false)
      {
         continue ;
      }
      foreach ($list as $file)
      {
         if (in_array($file, array('.', '..')))
         {
            continue ;
         }
         if (match($file, $pattern) > 0)
         {
            $matching_paths[] = rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $file;
         }
      }
   }
   if (count($dir_patterns) == 0)
   {
      return $matching_paths;
   }
   return ftp_glob_rec($resource, $dir_patterns, $matching_paths);
}

function match($string, $pattern, $a = 0, $b = 0, $options = '')
{
   if ((!isset($string[$a])) && (!isset($pattern[$b])))
   {
      return 1;
   }
   if (strpos($options, 'x') !== false)
   {
      if (($string[$a] == "\n") || ($string[$a] == "\t") || ($string[$a] == "\r") || ($string[$a] == " "))
      {
         return (match($string, $pattern, ($a + 1), $b, $options));
      }
      if (($pattern[$b] == "\n") || ($pattern[$b] == "\t") || ($pattern[$b] == "\r") || ($pattern[$b] == " "))
      {
         return (match($string, $pattern, $a, ($b + 1), $options));
      }
   }
   if ((isset($pattern[$b])) && ($pattern[$b] == '*'))
   {
      if (isset($string[$a]))
      {
         return (match($string, $pattern, ($a + 1), $b, $options) + match($string, $pattern, $a, ($b + 1), $options));
      }
      else
      {
         return (match($string, $pattern, $a, ($b + 1), $options));
      }
   }
   if ((isset($string[$a])) && (isset($pattern[$b])) && ($pattern[$b] == '?'))
   {
      return (match($string, $pattern, ($a + 1), ($b + 1), $options));
   }
   if ((isset($string[$a])) && (isset($pattern[$b])) && ($pattern[$b] == '\\'))
   {
      if ((isset($pattern[($b + 1)])) && ($string[$a] == $pattern[($b + 1)]))
      {
         return (match($string, $pattern, ($a + 1), ($b + 2), $options));
      }
   }
   if ((isset($string[$a])) && (isset($pattern[$b])) && ($string[$a] == $pattern[$b]))
   {
      return (match($string, $pattern, ($a + 1), ($b + 1), $options));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes thats correct, but it would be be pretty easy to use glob in a foreach loop and get all files in a directory.